# NoMethodError in JobsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting a no method error when trying to create a new job in my CRM project. I took this project over when I started at the company a month ago, have reviewed the codebase a few times and am not seeing the issue or where things are not adding up. I feel as if I am overlooking it due to being frustrated so I am asking for help from some seasoned Rails developers. Thanks in advance!

**Relevant section of Jobs Controller where error occurs:**

```
  # GET /jobs/new
  def new
    @job = Job.opportunity.new do |j|
      if params[:opportunity_id].present?
        j.opportunity_id = params[:opportunity_id]
      end
```

**Jobs/new view:**

```
<% @job[:opportunity_id] = params[:opportunity_id] %>
<% title "New #{@job.opportunity.name} Job"%>

<%
@job[:name] = @job.opportunity.name
@pm = @job.opportunity.pm_id


%>

<br><br>
<%= render 'form' %>
```

**Jobs model:**

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file1, AttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :cost_proposal
  belongs_to :opportunity

  def Job
    has_many :opportunities
  end
end
```

**Jobs table in schema.rb:**

```
  create_table 'jobs', force: true do |t|
    t.integer  'cost_proposal_id'
    t.string   'number'
    t.string   'name'
    t.date     'flight_date'
    t.string   'flight_sub'
    t.string   'camera'
    t.string   'roll'
    t.string   'map_type'
    t.integer  'plan_only'
    t.integer  'lab_only'
    t.integer  'est_hrs_model'
    t.date     'due_date'
    t.integer  'edge_job_id'
    t.integer  'custom_trans'
    t.integer  'comp_inhouse'
    t.date     'delivered_date'
    t.integer  'done'
    t.date     'control_in'
    t.string   'control_status'
    t.date     'at_date'
    t.string   'control_results'
    t.integer  'control_check'
    t.string   'scan_staff'
    t.date     'scan_date'
    t.integer  'scan_check'
    t.string   'comp_staff'
    t.date     'comp_date'
    t.integer  'comp_check'
    t.string   'comp_sub'
    t.date     'comp_sub_due_date'
    t.integer  'comp_sub_rec'
    t.string   'img_staff'
    t.date     'img_date'
    t.integer  'img_check'
    t.string   'edit_staff'
    t.date     'edit_date'
    t.integer  'edit_check'
    t.text     'notes'
    t.string   'file1'
    t.string   'file2'
    t.string   'file3'
    t.string   'file4'
    t.string   'file5'
    t.string   'add_files'
    t.datetime 'created_at'
    t.datetime 'updated_at'
    t.integer  'flown'
    t.integer  'cust_trans'
    t.integer  'delivered'
    t.string   'at_staff'
    t.integer  'at_check'
    t.integer  'opportunity_id'
  end
```

Comment: What is the error, on what line does it happen?

Comment: @PoloniculMov job = Job.opportunity.new do |j| is where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Your associations need some attention.  In your Job model, you have both opportunity and opportunities.  That is not how this should work.  You can have a primary_opportunity that is in the opportunities collection, but with a property set.

First of all, this is wrong:

```
  def Job
    has_many :opportunities
  end
```

<s>There should not be a method named Job (capital J), words that start with a capital letter are classes and constants, not methods.</s>
Class Methods (def Job) do not have the instance scope.  This is not a place for associations.  Put methods inside your `def Job` to create methods accessible before instantiation.  Associations should reside inside the instance methods definition (outside `def Job`)  Remove the def Job and end.  This will give you the model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file1, AttachmentUploader
  belongs_to :cost_proposal
  belongs_to :opportunity
  has_many :opportunities 
end
```

From there, you need to determine if you want to have a `belongs_to :opportunity` or a `has_many :opportunities` relationship.  If each Job has many of them, remove the `belongs_to`.

Second, your `@job = Job.opportunity.new do |j|` line is calling a method on a constant rather than an instance.  Change this line to:

```
@job = Job.new
@job.opportunties.new do |j|
```

The above code is assuming you use the `has_many` variant of your duplicated associations.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a shot. This is all code I did not write, so I am having to clean it all up and make it work properly. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: I have come to realize the associations in the project need some major attention. Thanks again.